# Leading zeros disappear when using bulk insert from file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, csv, bulkinsert

I am using `bulk insert` to insert data from a csv file to a SQL table. One of the columns in the csv file is an "ID" columns: i.e. each cell in the column is an "ID number" that may have leading zeros. Example: 00117701, 00235499, etc.

The equivalent column in the SQL table is of `varchar(255)` type.

When I bulk insert the data into the table, the leading zeros in each element of the "ID" column disappear. In other words, `00117701` becomes `117701`, etc.

Is this a column type problem? If not, what's the best way to overcome this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you open the file with a text editor, are the 0's there?

Comment: Yes they are. That was my first check.

Comment: Do you really have `ID` values that only differ in the number of leading zeros that they have? If so, I commiserate with you. But it's far more likely that these are merely *formatting* issues and you shouldn't be that concerned about the end result.

Comment: Well, they do not only differ by the number of leading zeros. However, I will have to cross-references this table with other tables where IDs do have the leading zeros. So it will be very annoying for me to either add leading zeros manually, or delete them from the other table, so that I could cross-reference them.

Comment: It almost sounds like the values are being converted to int in a transformation. Are you using a format file?

Answer (score 1):

not sure what is causing it to strip off the leading zeroes, but I had to 'fix' some data in the past and did something like this:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field> = RIGHT('00000000'+cast(<field> as varchar(8)),8)
```

You may need to adjust it a bit for your purposes, but maybe you get the idea from it?

Comment: Thanks @BWS. I was aware of that fix but was hoping to treat the problem at the source...